# May I need avoid composition without annotations with Hibernate and MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

In my project which is based on `Hibernate` and `MySQL` I'm using barcode so I have set `primary key` to `bracode` as well as `id` field and since there's composition it's problematic that occurring :

> org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class com.pojo.MyClass

So I'm not using @annotations
I've checked without composition and just make barcode unique rather set `primary key`  so would this approach could be cause of any future problem in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the barcode for you entity is unique identifier just put @Id annotation on this field and put the unique constrain in the data base for that field as well. If you are using several fields as unique constrain in this case you should use composite key.
If I get you question right.

Comment: I've just two fields that are unique id and barcode.

Comment: If they are different you should use composite key. If they are the same there is no sense to keep it like that and just use one filed as unique constraint.

Comment: Do you mean same data type?

Comment: I mean the same value. Because it is a bit unclear from your question.

Comment: It obvious are not same since they are id and barcode.

Comment: The main idea was that if you are using barcode as unique identifier there is no need to use Id as a separate field. If from some point like business logic you need Id as well, you could use embeddedId from Hibernate

Comment: I think id is also needed cause what if some items don't have barcode then I'll unable to search them.

Comment: For this case it is good idea to use id as id and barcode as another field because if it is nullable and several entities can have nullable barcodes it means that it is not unique constraint :)

Comment: Now I'v separated  both fields and removed composition currently I've skipped barcode part so I'll see it more deeper when I'll work on that. Thank you so much.